# Can I use make conditionals with elif too?

Tags: if-statement, testing, makefile, conditional-statements, comparison

I can do simple checks with [make's conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax), like that:

```sh
var = yes
ifeq $(var) "yes"; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

But the docs say nothing about `elif`. Can I do it like the following ?

```sh
var = yes
ifeq $(var) "yes"; then
    echo "yes"
elifeq $(var) "no"; then
    echo "no"
else
    echo "invalid"
fi
```

If not, is that possible at all, or do I have to make nested conditions or use `test` ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html

Comment: @MadScientist I already linked to that document in my question, but it does not answer my question, whether I can use `elifeq` or not.

Comment: The docs do cover the valid syntax.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do it like the following ?

No.  You cannot use `elifeq`.

> do I have to make nested conditions or use test ?

No.  The documentation says:

> The syntax of a complex conditional is as follows:
> ...
> or:
>
> ```
> conditional-directive-one
> text-if-one-is-true
> else conditional-directive-two
> text-if-two-is-true
> else
> text-if-one-and-two-are-false
> endif
> ```
>
> There can be as many “else conditional-directive” clauses as necessary.

Note here it says **else *conditional-directive-two***.  So, you can write:

```
var = yes
ifeq ($(var),yes)
    $(info "yes")
else ifeq ($(var),no)
    $(info "no")
else
    $(info "invalid")
endif
```

Note your original syntax is not valid makefile syntax.  It looks like you're trying to use shell syntax: a makefile is not a shell script and doesn't use the same syntax.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot - I was stupid not to think of _that_ !

Comment: "a makefile is not a shell script and doesn't use the same syntax." - wait, I thought I could use shell bits in a Makefile ? At least, I always did and it always worked ?!

Comment: "Note your original syntax is not valid makefile syntax" - which line do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I mean, almost all of them... the only lines that are valid are `var = yes` and `else`.  Compare my version with your version in your question.  The syntax of your conditions is not right, you shouldn't add quotes (quote characters are not special to make), you shouldn't add `; then` to your ifeq statements, the final token is `endif` not `fi`... and `echo` is not a valid makefile command.

Comment: "you shouldn't add quotes" - but in the examples in the docs there ___are___ quotes ?

Comment: There are, annoyingly, many ways to delimit the values to be compared.  One of those ways is using quotes.  But, the documentation shows **ifeq "arg1" "arg2"**.  You put quotes only around the _arg2_, while the documenation shows quotes around both arguments.  You can use quotes if you want to but if you do you must put them around _both_ arguments, as the docs show, not just one argument.  Else the statement is a syntax error.  You can easily just try this on your system to see what I mean, there's no need for a long discussion on SO.